# Why $g^{\prime}(\gamma(t)) = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)$ in Complex Analysis by Cain (ch4, pg 4.7)

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

At page 4.7 in chapter 4 of [this link](https://cain.math.gatech.edu/winter99/complex.html), the author writes:

$$\frac{d}{dt} g(\gamma(t)) = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 
i  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + i \frac{dy}{dt}\right) = g^{\prime}(\gamma(t))\gamma^{\prime}(t)$$

---

I understand that $\gamma^{\prime}(t) = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + i \frac{dy}{dt}\right)$ because $\gamma(t)$ is defined as
$x(t) + i y(t)$.

What I don't follow is why $g^{\prime}(\gamma(t)) = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 
i  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)$.

$$g(\gamma(t)) = u(x(t),y(t)) + i v(x(t),y(t))$$ so why are the partials only taken with respect to $x$ and not also $y$? Thanks

Comment: $g$ is complex differentiable (holomorphic), is it not?

Comment: yes, as far as I can tell.  I'm not so sure ( based on your comment and  the  answer below ) if my question was clear. My confusion is that I'm not understanding why $g^\prime(\gamma(t))$ is a function of only $dx$. Should it not be a function of $dy$ also ? Thanks.

Comment: the link I had originally was wrong so I fixed it. my apologies.

Comment: See page 2.9. …

Comment: thanks ted. I'll check it out. it's appreciated.

Comment: Ted: That was eye opening. I forgot that, in the complex world, the derivative has to be the same even if one keeps $y$ constant. Thanks a lot. It's also a lesson that one should not skip sections when reading something even if they think they know it.

Comment: Remember that complex differentiability is far stronger than real differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

$g:U \to \mathbb{C}$ where $U $ is a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.Let $g=u+iv $ and if the partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ exists and are continuous then $g$ is differentiable and $g'= u_x^{'}+iv_x^{'}$.
Similarly $g'= u_y^{'}+iv_y^{'}$.

The author could have used this result and wrote like this...

Comment: By the chain rule $g'(x+iy) = u_x(x,y) + iv_x(x,y)$ and $i g'(x+iy) = u_y(x,y) + iv_y(x,y)$, which implies $g'(x+iy) = v_y(x,y) - i u_x(x,y)$.